# What is the time complexity of this algorithm with two arrays?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the code below?

```
import math
arr1 = [2,3,5,6]
arr2 = [1,4,7,8,9,10,21]

for i in range(len(arr2)):
    #some operations

for i in range(len(arr1)):
    for j in range(2,int(math.sqrt(arr1[i]))):
        #some operations
```

Is O(n+m*q), where n is size of arr2 and m is size of arr1 correct? Can I simplify it? I just want to know what the complexity is when we searching for all elements in array then for all elements in another array we compute sqr(n) operations.

Comment: At first it is necessary to describe a problem. What should code do? Why arr2 is not really used?

Comment: Why is `for j in range(math.sqrt(arr1[i])):` being treated as iterable? `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. If your code snippet can't run your time complexity is probably O(1)

Comment: @roganjosh It's not O(1), as it crashes after the first loop.

Comment: Sorry i corrected it. I just want to know what the complexity is when we searching for all elements in array then for all elements in another array we compute sqr(n) operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`O(n + m * sqrt(k))`, where:

- `n` is the length of `arr2`;
- `m` is the length of `arr1`;
- `k` is the maximum number in `arr1`.

`sqrt(k)` is the same as `k**(1/2)`, so it's sublinear and therefore cannot be simplified to just `k`.

You may find more complete answers in the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Using O, you *can* simplify it to k. It would be correct, just even less tight.

Comment: @nocomment Formally you are right. Informally people will usually refer to the tighter bound (at least outside of academia). Your comment is appreciated, though, as that's more correct.